# Whats the difference with this razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view with the following razor...

```
foreach (var result in @Model.Results)
{
    if (result.Location != null && result.Location.Lat != null && result.Location.Long != null)
    {                   
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            var MapDataObj = (function () {
                mapDataObj = new Object();
                mapDataObj.Lat = @result.Location.Lat;
                mapDataObj.Long = @result.Location.Long;
                mapDataObj.BasedInArea = 'True';
                SearchMapDataProperties.searchResultsArray.push(mapDataObj);
                return {

                };
            }());
        </script>
    }
```

But when I change it to...

```
foreach (var result in @Model.Results)
{
    if (result.Location != null && result.Location.Lat != null && result.Location.Long != null)
    {                   
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            var MapDataObj = (function () {
                mapDataObj = new Object();
                mapDataObj.Lat = result.Location.Lat;
                mapDataObj.Long = result.Location.Long;
                mapDataObj.BasedInArea = 'True';
                SearchMapDataProperties.searchResultsArray.push(mapDataObj);
                return {

                };
            }());
        </script>
    }
```

(I have removed the '@' symbol from the result.Location object) I get a null reference exception on the result.Location.

I'm really confused about the difference. Its obviously still treating it as c# because I get a YSOD. I just cant fathom what the difference is...

Pete

Answer (score 2):

`@result` is referencing a view model (an object within the enumerable `Model.Results` being iterated through your `foreach`). When you remove the `@` you're now trying to reference a JavaScript object called `result` (which is presumably undefined).

If you want this kind of control. you can use Newtonsoft's JSON library and serialize the model to `result` (something like:)

```
var result = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Results));
```

(Assuming you has a `Json.Encode` helper) which could make `Model.Results` look something like this after it's serialized in HTML:

```
var result = [
  {"Location":{"Lat":"0.00","Long":"0.00"}},
  {"Location":{"Lat":"0.00","Long":"0.00"}}
];
```

Ir, of course, the single instance for:

```
var result = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(result));
// result = {"Location":{"Lat":"0.00","Long":"0.00"}}
```

Which now will work when referencing `result` without razor.

Comment: Never once noted a JavaScript error invoking .NET exceptions and causing YSOD.

Comment: Grant agreed I dont think I would be getting a YSOD if this was a javascript error either...

Answer (score 0):

With Razor, using the `@` prefix seems to handle null instances (presumably by returning an empty string) whereas in "C# proper" you don't get this safety mechanism, you'll have to check that `Location` is not null.